# Neo4j - Specific relationship vs Label

Tags: neo4j, cypher

[newbie question] I'm kinda in doubt if it's better using specific relationships or labels, but first let me give you a little bit more context.

Suppose that the graph should be able to answer the following questions/queries:

- Given a person, return all the emails associated;
- Given a person, return all the contacts;

I've come up with these 2 possible models:

[image: multiple labels]

[image: multiple relationships]

They're both able to fulfill the required requests with the following queries:

First model:

- ```
  MATCH (p:Person {name:"Bob"})-[:REACHABLE_BY]-(e:Email)
  RETURN p.name AS Name, e.contact​ AS Contact
  ```
- ```
  MATCH (p:Person {name:"Bob"})-[:REACHABLE_BY]-(c:Contact)
  RETURN p.name AS Name, c.contact​ AS Contact
  ```

Second model:

- ```
  MATCH (p:Person {name:"Bob"})-[:REACHABLE_BY_EMAIL]-(c:Contact)
  RETURN p.name AS Name, c.contact​ AS Contact
  ```
- ```
  MATCH (p:Person {name:"Bob"})-[:REACHABLE_BY_FAX]-(c:Contact)
  RETURN p.name AS Name, c.contact AS Contact
  UNION ALL
  MATCH (p)-[:REACHABLE_BY_EMAIL]-(c2:Contact)
  RETURN p.name AS Name, c2.contact AS Contact
  ```

But I'm wondering if there's a best practice to follow in this case. I mean, I know that having specific relationships in some cases is better since we reduce the number of nodes involved in the query (instead of filtering later by some property), but I feel like that in this case we can achieve the same result (maybe also in performance) by considering different labels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both of your models will work fine. But to obtain the best performance, you can combine these two models into a single one. Like this:

1. All the `Contact` nodes that store emails, will have `Email` label as well.
2. All the `Contact` nodes that store faxes will have `Fax` label as well.
3. Relationship type between `Person` and `Email` types node will be `REACHABLE_BY_EMAIL`
4. Relationship type between `Person` and `Fax` types node will be `REACHABLE_BY_FAX`

Using this model, you can easily query a person's email or by these queries:

```
MATCH (p:Person)-[:REACHABLE_BY_EMAIL]->(email)
RETURN p, email

MATCH (p:Person)-[:REACHABLE_BY_FAX]->(fax)
RETURN p, fax
```

Note, that I have not specified `Email` or `Fax` labels in the query, as they are redundant.

Also, now you can query your the emails and faxes, using simply

```
MATCH (e:Email) RETURN e
MATCH (f:Fax) RETURN f
```

If the need arises.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use

```
(:Person)-[:REACHABLE_BY]->(:Contact)-[:HAS_TYPE]->(:ContactType)
```

with 'Fax', 'Phone', 'Email' as ContactType nodes.

In your queries, using directions will help you speed up things. Your 2nd query of the second model can be written as

```
MATCH (p:Person {name:"Bob"})-->(c:Contact)
RETURN p.name AS Name, c.contact AS Contact
```

For the model I suggest, the queries would be:

```
MATCH (p:Person {name:"Bob"})-->(c:Contact)-->(:ContactType {name:'Email'})
RETURN p.name AS Name, c.contact​ AS Contact
```

and

```
MATCH (p:Person {name:"Bob"})-->(c:Contact)
RETURN p.name AS Name, c.contact​ AS Contact
```